# Solr json DSL constant score query

Tags: solr

Since solr 5.1 we can use constant score operator - ^= to set-up particular score for matched docs.

Is it possible to use somehow constant score operator in JSON DSL query syntax https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11244 ? Or maybe there are other ways to achieve constant score for particular query in JSON dsl ?

I know about Boolean query and filter clause,  I'm asking to ability change score to other values.

Comment: Did you try to use it directly in the query as you'd do in a normal query?